# Diffing text with html tags

Tags: ruby, rubygems, diff

I have been wanting to either find or write a new diffing gem that will not only highlight changes in text but also changes in HTML structure as well.  Here's a quick example of what I mean.

Right now most diffing gems or algos out there will take something like:

```
a = "<p>I am some text</p>"
b = "<p>I was some text</p>"
MyDiffer.diff(a,b)
=> "<p>I <del>am</del><ins>was</ins> some text</p>"
```

However, when HTML tags are thrown in most of them don't properly account.  I'd like to see something like this:

```
a = "<p>I am <strong>some</strong> text</p>"
b = "<p>I was some text</p>"
MyDiffer.diff(a,b)
=> "<p>I <del>am</del><ins>was</ins> <del class='htmlchange'><strong>some</strong></del><ins class="htmlchange">some</ins></p>"
a = "<p>I am a sentence.  I am another sentence.</p>"
b = "<p>I am a sentence.</p><p>I am another sentence.</p>"
MyDiffer.diff(a,b)
=> "<p>I am a sentence.<del class="htmlchange">I am another sentence</del></p><ins class="htmlchange"><p>I am another sentence</p></ins>"
```

Does something like this exists out there?  If not, I'm not entirely sure how to go about building something along these lines.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML you'll want to use a parser, such as Nokogiri, which will do some cleanup and normalizing for you. Then you'll want to reformat the document's tags so the parameters are in consistent order. I'd recommend a simple alphabetic sort using the parameter's name.

Nokogiri's `to_html` method will be useful when outputting the results of your restructuring.

You'll also need to decide if whitespace will be retained or removed in text-nodes, and whether parameter and tag-name case is honored.

You could try doing it without relying on a parser, but I think you'd go nuts. HTML is too unstructured and irregular to do more than a simple diff.

Comment: Yeah... I envisioned running the diff twice to 1) first remove all html tags and just diff the text against the old stuff, then 2) generating an array of html tags (text.scan(/(<.*?>/)) and comparing the arrays against eachother... Where things get sticky is when there are multiple tags within eachother (div>span>em>mytext) or when a word was changed and also had html formatting added.  It's an interesting problem that is even difficult to think about going properly, much less generating it algorithmically.

Comment: You can't use a regular expression to parse HTML. HTML is waaaaay to irregular, which can cause you to miss almost every tag, or worse, grab text that isn't tags, thinking it is. It's often cited here on SO, but there are some very good comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454

Comment: You can use regular expressions to find tags within HTML, but shouldn't rely on it for actual parsing.  To just extract a list of tags, regular expressions is sufficient, especially considering the input to this gem will be (at least in my use case) completely valid markup.

Comment: "You can use regular expressions to find tags within HTML".  `'<input type="textbox" value="a>b>c">'.scan(/(<.*?>)/)`

Comment: I guess I should've prefaced that I'm only trying to diff article text here, so odd characters within attributes are not going to be an issue.  My use case is limited, so for my purposes, regexp html tags is totally fine.  Essentially just diffing parsed markdown.  The only tags that will be in the text being diffed are simple markup tags (p/br/strong/em/h1/h2/h3).